# Escape Single Quote in Javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

In First link it works well there is no CSS Class specified for Table,For second one CSS Class specified.First one works second one breaks.Thanks in Advance.

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/joekingleo/BLsAZ/)

```
<a onclick='showSchedulePopup(this,\"<table ><tr><td>000</td></tr></table>\");'>002</a>

<br><br><br>

<a onclick='showSchedulePopup(this,\"<table class='popupCSS'><tr><td>000</td></tr></table>\");'>002</a>
```

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/BLsAZ/1/

Comment: Do you have to put the event in the html? Is there any reason you can't write a script, or a js file?

Comment: <a onclick='showSchedulePopup(this,\"<table class=\"popupCSS\"><tr><td>000</td></tr></table>\");'>002</a> ?

Comment: You don't need escaping at all. Because, you don't really need to wrap the properties in quotes! See this: ***http://jsfiddle.net/BLsAZ/3/***

Comment: You shouldn't really be using inline events.

Answer (score 0):

You used single quote in `class='popupCSS'`use double quotes `class="popupCSS"`. it would work..

```
<a href="#" onclick='showSchedulePopup(this,\"<table ><tr><td>000</td></tr></table>\");'>002</a>

    <br><br><br>

    <a href="#" onclick='showSchedulePopup(this,\"<table class="popupCSS"><tr><td>000</td></tr></table>\");'>002</a>
```

[Demo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLsAZ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

change with

```
<a onclick="showSchedulePopup(this,'<table ><tr><td>000</td></tr></table>');">002</a>

<br><br><br>

<a onclick="showSchedulePopup(this,'<table class=\"popupCSS\"><tr><td>000</td></tr></table>');">002</a>
```